# Running links to batch files from another batch file and use the shortcut layout properties

Tags: batch-file, cmd, shortcut-file

I have a set of 7 batch files I keep running all night at work, monitoring directories and files.  I have shortcuts created and used the Layout tab to arrange and resize them so I can still use my desktop.  I just created an extremely simple batch file I use to start the other 7.  But when I run it all the new windows open on top of each other. I can't figure out how to use the Layouts I have set up for each shortcut so the command shells open in the positions and sizes I need.
"start everything.bat"

```
@echo off
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file1.bat.lnk"
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file2.bat.lnk"
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file3.bat.lnk"
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file4.bat.lnk"
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file5.bat.lnk"
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file6.bat.lnk"
start cmd /c call "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file7.bat.lnk"
```

Is it possible to get the new windows how and where I need them, or am I pretty much stuck just running the shortcuts manually?  This is running on Windows Server 2012, and like I said it's at work so I don't have access to install anything, or use any 3rd party apps.

Comment: Why not `for /L %%I in (1,1,7) do start "" "J:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file%%I.bat.lnk"` or `for %%I in ("J:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\batch file?.bat.lnk") do start "" "%%~I"` or `cd /D "J:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts" && for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "batch file?.bat.lnk"') do start "" "%%I"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the `.lnk` files, view the `properties` and goto the `layout` tab.

[image]

In the *"window position"* section, remove the tick for *"let system position window"* and then adjust where each window should be located, apply and exit.

Now, in your batch calling all the batch links, change to this:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\*.lnk") do start "" "%%~fi"
```

If however there are more `.lnk` files and you only want to open some, then do:

```
@echo off
set links="batch file1.bat.lnk" "batch file2.bat.lnk" "batch file3.bat.lnk" "batch file4.bat.lnk" "batch file5.bat.lnk" "batch file6.bat.lnk" "batch file7.bat.lnk"
for %%i in (%links%) do start "" "j:\network drive with spaces\shortcuts\%%~i"
```

Comment: I tried that just now.  It resulted in 7 command windows opening, with the path to the shortcut in the title bar, but the actual batch jobs didn't run.  Also, instead of using the layouts I have set up, they were all default sized and cascaded in front of each other.

Comment: I made a change by adding the title comments to the `start` command, copy the code as is and try again.

Comment: I changed the do to be 'do start cmd /c call'  Now it opens the links as separate windows, but still the default size and locations, and still cascaded.  I do have the _"Let system position window"_ unchecked for all of them.

Comment: no, don't do that. just do `start "" "%%~fi"` You also have to position the windows programmatically by setting the `left` and `top` positions as in the screenshot.

Comment: That change did it!  Now they are opening in the desired locations with the sizes I have set.  Thank you so much.  For what it's worth, I copied the shortcuts I need to a different folder for ease of typing.  But now I'm going to change the batch file to the second code you posted, so it only starts the ones I need.

Comment: Cool. As long as you retain the format I use in the `start` sections for both code sets I posted.

Comment: In the second code set, I kept getting an error message about not being able to find the batch files.  Once I realized they had spaces in the names and changed the end to `shortcuts\"%%i""` it's working just great!

Comment: That is why my example has the qoutes in the `set` command and the full path is quoted in the `start` section. The way you are quoting now is wrong. quote the entire path like I did. `start "" "full path\%%~i"`

Comment: I'm not sure what I had wrong, but I changed it back to what you did and it works not.  Thank you for your help.